# How to export all the product information for all the products from the list into a csv after scraping?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I made a python scraping program using selenium. How can I export all the information about products in the urls list into csv. Now my program returns only one product. So it will be 2 columns(Product title, Product price) and 4 rows with one header and 3 product information.
I have to use selenium and python for this program. I will appreciate any help.

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv

# set the proxies to hide actual IP

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://62.117.72.122:8080',
    'https': 'http://185.93.3.123:8080',
}


urls = ["https://www.amazon.com/Haggar-Hidden-Comfort-Waist-Plain/dp/B0018Q3BRO/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1518006207&sr=8-3&keywords=trousers+for+men",
"https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0118QC1BA/ref=s9_acsd_cdeal_hd_bw_bFmNr_c_x_w?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-5&pf_rd_r=AZJF41VDFJMPA4XY6D95&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=32a36b64-58af-5269-b81a-c1030ee0250c&pf_rd_i=3760911",
        "https://www.amazon.com/URbeauty-Aromatherapy-Peppermint-Eucalyptus-Lemongrass/dp/B078B9JRPM/ref=pd_sim_201_5?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B078B9JRPM&pd_rd_r=2GC7WEGK2P019AMS5VPC&pd_rd_w=DURLb&pd_rd_wg=jnjzt&psc=1&refRID=2GC7WEGK2P019AMS5VPC"
       ]
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxies)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=chrome_options)
for i in range(len(urls)):
   driver.get(urls[i])
sleep(3)
product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"][1]')
product_price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"][1]')

prod_title = [x.text for x in product_title]
prod_price = [x.text for x in product_price]

csvfile = 'products-10-02.csv'

header = ['Product title', 'Product price']
data = [prod_title[0], prod_price[0]]

with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: It looks like you have some code.  where does it fail?  what is the specific problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: It returns only one product in the csv. But I would like to return all the products. The problem with the code starts with this line header = ['Product title', 'Product price'] and finish with this line  writer.writerow(data).

Comment: use "with open(csvfile, "a") as output" in your file

Comment: @Narendra this won't solve the problem.

Comment: @AndreiGhervan please _edit your post_ to clearly explain the problem - it's an essential part of a good question and doesn't belong in a comment.

Comment: Ok I will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You should have a csv output with the required data. I kicked out `proxies` from the below script as it is not working in my end. Now it is good to go.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time ; import csv

urls = ("https://www.amazon.com/Haggar-Hidden-Comfort-Waist-Plain/dp/B0018Q3BRO/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1518006207&sr=8-3&keywords=trousers+for+men",
        "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0118QC1BA/ref=s9_acsd_cdeal_hd_bw_bFmNr_c_x_w?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-5&pf_rd_r=AZJF41VDFJMPA4XY6D95&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=32a36b64-58af-5269-b81a-c1030ee0250c&pf_rd_i=3760911",
        "https://www.amazon.com/URbeauty-Aromatherapy-Peppermint-Eucalyptus-Lemongrass/dp/B078B9JRPM/ref=pd_sim_201_5?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B078B9JRPM&pd_rd_r=2GC7WEGK2P019AMS5VPC&pd_rd_w=DURLb&pd_rd_wg=jnjzt&psc=1&refRID=2GC7WEGK2P019AMS5VPC"
       )

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for itemlink in range(len(urls)):
    driver.get(urls[itemlink])

    time.sleep(3)

    product_title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#productTitle').text.strip()
    product_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#priceblock_ourprice').text.strip()

    with open('products-10-02.csv', "a", newline="") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow([product_title,product_price])

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it only exports the first data row - that's what you explicitely asked for:

```
# here - your `data` is a single row...
data = [prod_title[0], prod_price[0]]

with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)
    # and here: you call `writerow` only once
    writer.writerow(data)
```

To export all the collected data, you need to either loop over them row by row:

```
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)
    # zip(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3]) => [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)] 
    for row in zip(prod_title, prod_price):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

or just pass the whole list of rows to `writer.writerows()` (note the plural):

```
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(zip(prod_title, prod_price))
```

Comment: @AndreiGhervan "it's not working" is the most useless possible description of a problem - and actually those are the two correct ways to write your rows to the csv, so whatever "is not working" for you, it's a different issue.